# "The great I" vs "The great me"

Tags: grammar, pronouns, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case

Are both sentences below grammatically correct?

> The great I.
>
> The great me.

What is the grammatical breakdown in each case?

Comment: This reminds me of a movie title: "Despicable me."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a sentence unless it's an exclamation (*The great me!*). In that case, it would seem to be proclaiming *I am great* in its illocutionary force, but grammar-wise, it would be just stating something in isolation without a clear syntactic role, so *me* as the objective case would be most appropriate, similar to the reply to the question: '*Who wants cake?*' *Me!*

Comment: Who wants lots of cake?  The great me!

Comment: @GEdgar I guess my subconscious is influencing my answer. It is lunch time here... :)

Answer (score 5):

Neither of those sentences are correct without a verb (unless they're exclaimed).

Answer (score 2):

Neither phrase is idiomatic, but there is *The great I am* as a term for a self-important person (possibly from an Old Testament name of God).